# Concatenation of string in an array into a long string in Lua

Tags: string, lua, string-concatenation, lua-table

I have this so far

```
mk= {}
mk = conn:query({ live=true, sql="select * from OrderReports where OrderId= '"..T.OrderId.."'"})
 for a=1, # mk do

 end
```

I want strings at different indexes in `mk` to be concatenated and stored in a variable let's say `lk`, what should be in the body ?

Comment: Be wary of concatenating strings to get data into SQL queries; it opens the door to SQL injection attacks. While this example is probably not too insecure, it's better to use prepared statements and binding if the the engine supports it (and all competent ones should).

Answer (score 5):

The direct way is to concatenate the strings in the `for` body like this:

```
local lk = ""
for a = 1, # mk do
    lk = lk .. mk[a]
end
```

But this has a poor performance when the table is large because strings are immutable in Lua. A new string is created and the contents are copied in each loop.

Instead, you should use the built-in function [`table.concat()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) for this job:

```
local lk = table.concat(mk)
```

Comment: The first one gives error that says nodes with children can not be used in concatenaton.

Comment: second one gives error saying" bad argument #1 to '?' (table expected, got userdata"

Comment: @Simrankaur You said `mk` is an array, in Lua, that means it's a table with index from `1` to some integral value only. But from your error message, it's not, its type is `userdata`.

Comment: Thank you Yu hao, it worked  :), that was error because of something else, My mistake .thanks :)